# What are C++ manipulators?

Tags: c++

What are C++ manipulators? C++ defines varioss types of manipulators, but what are they? What do they do?

Comment: Check out the discussion of iostreams in Josuttis' book, *The C++ Standard Library*.

Answer (score 4):

Searching Google for "c++ manipulator" return [this excellent page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/) as the first result. Basically it's a function which if passed to a stream changes the stream's behaviour.

Comment: More like a function which, if itself passed to a stream, changes the stream's behaviour. And if you pass the stream to the manipulator then you get the same result as inserting the manipulator into the stream. About the only thing you can't do is pass the result of the function to the stream, although the parameterized stream manipulators like `setw` confuse the issue further ;-)

Comment: Right you are. I was thinking of parametrized manipulators. Fixed, thanks.